# React file uploader does not trigger when same file is update twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

You can find a runnable code example here
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o74y4omzxy), just try uploading the same image twice, only 1 log will appear.

Basically, I have this code

```
<div>
  <input
    accept="image/*"
    className={classes.input}
    id="raised-button-file"
    multiple
    type="file"
    onChange={e => console.log(e)}
  />
  <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
    <Button raised component="span" className={classes.button}>
      Upload
    </Button>
  </label>
</div>
```

the problem is that if I upload the same file twice consecutively the `onChange` method is not triggered the second time. 
I mean ok, the file is the same, but at least the timestamp of upload has changed :/.

Is there another prop I can use to be triggered everytime a file is uploaded? I want to make some checks on the file, like checking if the size is not too big.

Comment: Do you clear the input after uploading the first one? Otherwise selecting the same file again would not trigger the input change as nothing has changed.

Comment: what about reseting the field after logging e => {
          console.log(e);
          e.target.value = ''
        }

Comment: Yep, I didn't know I had to clear the input. This did the trick `e.target.value = null;`. Thanks